# How do I programmatically find the path to OpenMP's shared library?

Tags: gcc, openmp

When I want to use OpenMP on my machine I compile a C program with

```
gcc -fopenmp
```

and include

```
-lgomp
```

as a linker flag. However, for the OpenMP `.so` file to actually get found, I also need to include the path to libgomp.so:

```
-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.3/
```

Obviously, this is brittle and won't work across machines. Is there some way to query gcc to find out where it put libgomp.so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`libgomp.so` is part of the GCC support infrastructure and is not intended to be used as a separate library. `-fopenmp` is all you need to specify on the command line in order to get OpenMP support turned on and the library linked automatically. Simply use `gcc -fopenmp -o executable file1.o file2.o ...` instead of `ld` to link your executable.

Answer (score 2):

You're really supposed to let the runtime linker find the dynamic libraries for you. If the directory containing the `.so` is in `/etc/ld.so.conf` (or, equivalently in many modern Linux distros, in a file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`) and you've run `ldconfig` as root, the runtime linker should be able to find the `.so`.

If you want to augment/change the compiled-in linker path (provided to the compile-time linker via `-L`) at runtime, there are two relevant environment variables `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LD_PRELOAD`:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/directory/containing/so ./foo

$ LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/so/to/load.so.0.1.2 ./foo
```

Comment: `libgomp` is part of GCC and it's not located in the standard library search path (i.e. not in `/etc/ld.so.conf(.d)`).